# Custom button url for Lead in LEX

Tags: custom-button, custom-url

I have a custom button url to open a Lead conversion page:

```
/lead/leadconvert.jsp?retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}&id={!Lead.Id}&nooppti=1
```

It still displays in lightning but open the convert page in classic!
I have tried:

```
{! URLFOR( $Action.Lead.Convert, Lead.Id) }
```

Same behaviour, use a page in classic.

```
{! URLFOR( "/apex/leadconvert", null, [id=Lead.Id] ) }
```

I got an error message: "Page leadconvert does not exist".

```
{! URLFOR( "/lead/leadconvert", null, [id=Lead.Id] ) }
```

I got an error message: "URL no longer exists".

Any idea how to write it to open the page in Lightning.
I need this URL to create a Lightning action to do some validation before opening the standard Lightning Component.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Sylvie

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning, the standard lead conversion process is in a modal and it is not accessible by URL.  Unfortunately your only solution is to write a custom lead conversion process to override the standard process.

Comment: Thank you. Any link/code you can provide to start with?

Answer (score 0):

you can use lightning navigation component to navigate to standard lead conversion page but in lightning lead conversion page the cancel button is not gonna work in my opinion I would recommnd you to use the classic URL for lead conversion page or you can use apex  for lead conversion
for the lightning lead conversion page you should go through this link
[How to redirect to standard lead convert page in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302605/how-to-redirect-to-standard-lead-convert-page-in-lightning)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to access the lead conversion on lightning:

/lightning/cmp/runtime_sales_lead__convertDesktopConsole?leadConvert__leadId={!Lead.Id}

Basically "/lightning/cmp/runtime_sales_lead__convertDesktopConsole" renders the new UI/Lightning Lead Conversion where "/lead/leadconvert.jsp" renders the old in Classic. It took me a quite lot of reading and some ideas from posts such as the one below to get to it. However, you will find that it will render on the same page even with a custom button action to open in a new window because of a salesforce bug/limitation which is very annoying. You will need a Lightning Component / Aura Bundle to handle this.

Reference: https://copyprogramming.com/howto/editing-custom-lead-convert-vf-page